# What is the difference between -さ and -み suffixes to make a noun out of an adjective?

Tags: nuances, adjectives, suffixes, nominalization

For example, both 悲しさ and 悲しみ are glossed as “sadness” in JMdict. What's the difference?

According to *A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar*, 〜み “is more emotive and concrete characterization of some state”, while 〜さ “describes, in an analytical manner, the degree of state represented by an adjective”.

The book uses a few examples to highlight the difference, but I can't make sense of it.

Answer (score 31):

They both mean the same thing but the nuance is as follows:

```
〜さ (as in 悲しさ、楽しさ、痛さ) indicates a degree or an amount of 〜
〜み (as in 悲しみ、楽しみ、痛み）indicates a state of being
```

I find the following contrasting examples as definitive:

> A:「痛さはどれくらいですか？」 = implies amount
>
> B:「痛み**の程**はどれくらいですか？」 = we add 程{ほど} to indicate an amount

However, to make things easier (or harder) **B** is starting to imply "an amount" too (I'll see if I can find an example).

My supposition is that **A** was originally "the correct way", but so many people used the incorrect way that *it* is becoming correct; *just like in English, meh!*

On OKWave I found the following useful examples:

```
「痛み」：　痛むこと、痛んでいる状態にあること = Pain, in a state of pain 
「痛さ」：　どれだけ痛んでいるかの状態・程度 = A state indicating how much pain, an amount

○「私達の心の痛みがわかりますか」＝「私達の心が痛んでいることがわかりますか」
   => Do you understand that our hearts are pained (by this)?

○「私達の心の痛さがわかりますか」＝「私達の心がどれだけ痛んでいるかがわかりますか」
   => Do you understand exactly how much our hearts are pained (by this)?

△「かなりの痛みだ」(NG)
○「かなりの痛さだ」＝ very painful

○「かなりの痛みがある」＝ very painful
△「かなりの痛さがある」 (NG)

Note, preceding「がある」the most appropriate option is「痛み」.

○「軽い痛みがある」＝ a little painful
△「軽い痛さがある」 (NG)
```

(Source: http://okwave.jp/qa/q6754018.html)

Answer (score 25):

`〜さ` seems to describe a "measurable" amount, while `〜み` seems to describe a general concept of the adjective.

> - 悲しみ - the general concept of sadness
> - 映画の悲しさ - the (amount of) sadness of that movie (possibly compared to other movies).

That's how I tend to compare them.

Also note that many of these types of adjective have corresponding verbs, such as `悲しむ`、`楽しむ`、`痛む`.  The `～み`　is just the stem of the `～ます` form, which is often used as a noun.  So this might help distinguish them a little.  For example:

> 帰り (the return), 踊り (a dance), 痛み (a pain), 楽しみ (enjoyment, fun)

Answer (score 2):

the 悲しみ　version could be re-written as 悲しく感じ, though not 100% accurate is a way to easily remember what the meaning is.  This would be the feeling of sadness.

さ i like to liken to 差, which means difference or level.  So 悲しさ would be level of sadness