# What is the purpose of the suffix "さ" on adjectives?

Tags: grammar, translation, nuances, conjugations

What is the purpose of the suffix "さ" on adjectives like 美しさ and 多さ?

The former is the title of an essay by Banana Yoshimoto, so I don't have much context for it.  The book editors translated it as "On beauty" which didn't help me understand what this さ business was all about.

In the case of the latter, she writes:

> "品揃えの多さについつい買い込んでしまい、大荷物を抱えて併設の花屋に行った。"

Which I understand as:

> "There were many goods there that, against my better judgement, I had purchased. Carrying the bags I went to the attached flower shop."

Comment: Related:  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1417/78

Comment: “In this case 美しさ.”  In which case?

Comment: It's the title of the essay, so I didn't have much context for it. The book editors translated it as "On beauty" which didn't help me understand what this さ business was all about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It serves the same purpose as "-ness" in English; making an adjective into a noun.

> [速]{はや}さ = speed; quickness
>   
> [高]{たか}さ = height; "tallness"
>   
> [長]{なが}さ　= length; "longness"
>   
> [新]{あたら}しさ　= newness
>   
> [大]{おお}きさ = size; largeness

and in your case:

> [多]{おお}さ = multitude
>   [美]{うつく}しさ = beauty

So in this context, the expression means "I, against my better judgement, bought a **multitude** of goods."

Comment: Your translation is only for the part ついつい買い込んでしまい.  In particular, the bold “multitude” does not correspond to 多さ in the original sentence.

Answer (score 13):

As phoenixheart6 wrote, suffix -さ makes a noun from an adjective.  I am not sure if you have a problem with this.  But it seems that you have a misunderstanding about the role of に.  In a sentence

> 品揃えの多さについつい買い込んでしまった。

に means “because of.”  買い込む means “to buy many things.”  Therefore, it means:

> Because of the variety of goods they sell, I ended up buying too many things against my better judgment.

Comment: Yes, I usually understand に in the context of moving in a direction or time, so に being used in the the sense of causing something was lost on me.

Comment: The particle に is definitely my Achilles heel when it comes to particles. Thanks for catching me on that.