# What does the Verb きれる mean here?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

I’m reading a manga and I’m a little confused to the meaning of きれる in this context.

> “甘さを自覚した三浦くんは
>   私に受け止めきれるかな”

When I asked one of my friends she told me it’s along the lines “I’ve realized the sweet side Miura-kun has towards me and I wonder how I can get completely used to it.”
I understand that きれる can also mean completely so, is that correct? Or is it more along the lines “I wonder If i will be able to handle Miura-kun, who has noticed how sweet he is himself?”
Thank you very much.[image]

Answer (score 10):

Yes this 切れる is the potential form of 切る, which means "completely". See also: [Is there any difference in meaning between 「抜け切る」 and 「抜ける」?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33789/5010)

甘さを自覚した三浦くん means "Miura-kun who is aware of his (own) sweetness". <del>This 甘さ is [考えの甘さ](http://pinasan.com/english/today_study/16251)</del>. The sentence is not saying "sweet side of Miura-kun" (三浦くんの甘さ). If you are still not good at relative clauses, please review its grammar now. 三浦くん is the subject of 自覚する.

I don't know how to translate 受け止める since there is not enough context. If this is a battle manga, this 受け止める should mean "to stop/endure his blow/attack". If this is a love story, it should mean something like "to accept him".

> 甘さを自覚した三浦くんは私に受け止めきれるかな。
>   I wonder if I can fully accept/stop Miura-kun, who is now aware of his (own) sweetness...

Comment: I would be very grateful if you could also give some explanation about 甘さ. In the dictionary,   "naive" is only listed under 甘い, please let us know how it becomes 甘さ.

Comment: Yes I would also appreciate it! being that this is a romance manga i’m Reading the female lead is referring to his “sweetness” since she refers to him as honey lemon soda.

Comment: @QuinceBlossom this question and answer should explain it quite well. https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6665/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-suffix-%E3%81%95-on-adjectives

Comment: @Crumcake Oh, in that case 甘さ can mean sweetness, but I don't understand why she said 受け止めきれるかな then. Maybe Miura is an eccentric character? Next time please always to include the context in your question.

Comment: Yes I’m so sorry this is my first time using this website ! So I apologize I will try to post up pictures once I figure out how to use it lol

Comment: @naruto there we go I posted the context! Once again I apologize for not doing this originally!

Comment: @Crumbcake Okay, so this 甘さ is "sweetness" rather than "naiveness". He's trying to take advantage of his allure (or "sweetness") to predominate over her, and she is wondering if she can resist it. I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

This is intended as a supplement to naruto's answer.

It might be easier to understand きれる via an easier example first. Take the verb 食べる (to eat). First attach きる to the base (continuative form /連用形) of the verb to make the verb:

> 食べきる to eat it all, eat everything until it is finished ([definition)](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%B9%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8B)

Now you can make the potential form of 食べきる (godan) by changing it to:

> 食べきれる to able to eat it all, be able to eat everything until it is finished

As for 受け止めきれる, please refer to naruto's answer.

Comment: @Crumbcake if it was useful, I'd appreciate some love ; )

Comment: I found it to be quite helpful!