# How to say "If you can't finish the food..."

Tags: sentence

I am wondering how to say "If you can't finish the food, ..." in Japanese.

Googling a bit tells me it's "料理が終わらないなら、...", but it doesn't sound very right to me.

A slightly better sentence would probably be "もう食べられないなら、...", but it doesn't really translate well, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close.

> もう食べられないなら

Is roughly "if you can't eat anymore". If you want to discuss someone's ability to "finish the food" in the sense of eating all of it, you want `食べきる`. You can see [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/what-does-the-verb-%E3%81%8D%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B-mean-here/63280#63280) for more detail.

So, I would likely say

> 食べきれなかったら

That said, I'm not going to talk about which conditional expression you should use - ultimately  it depends on precisely what you want to express, and there is already an [answer discussing that in detail](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/393/differences-among-%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89-%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-%E3%81%88%E3%81%B0-etc/1784#1784).